# indefinite article in 'he had gone from A to a that of B'

Tags: indefinite-article

This is from [a *TIME* article](https://time.com/6158182/vitalik-buterin-ethereum-profile/).

> The ensuing conflicts left Buterin with culture shock. In the space of
> a few months, he had gone from a cloistered life of writing code and
> technical articles to **a** that of a decisionmaker grappling with
> bloated egos and power struggles.

I wonder why there is the indefinite article 'a' in bold here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a typo (typographical error). It is incorrect. Good catch!

Comment: Thank you very much.